# Firebase Crashlytics issue: Some crashes are not reporting correctly from my iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, crashlytics

I have a project which is developed in Objective C, and I have integrated a firebase crashlytics into it. And have given a button for a forced crash. The below shown is the button action that I have used to force a crash.

```
- (IBAction)crashButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@""];
    NSString *str = [array objectAtIndex:3];
}
```

But the problem is, when I crash the app through this force crash button, that means, crashed by  `- (IBAction)crashButtonTapped:(id)sender;`, it is not reporting crashes perfectly to the firebase crashlytics on the dashboard, and it is reporting on the dSYMs tab on the firebase as optional dSYM. It is shown in the below screenshot.
[image]
But if I got a crash inside my application unexpectedly, the crash will report perfectly on the firebase dashboard. This crash is occurred when I try to remove a cell from an indexPath in when the `numberOfRowsInSection` in the tableView is 0.
The debug console reason for this crash is:

`NSInternalInconsistencyException: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (387), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 194 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).`

The report from the crashlytics for this crash is shown in the below screenshot and is perfectly reported:
[image]

*I have enabled the "Bitcode Enabled" to true in the Build Settings*

So my question is, why this odd this is happening and is there any filtration in firebase for the crash type or something like that?